# WSO2 Excel connector

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Does WSO2 have an Excel connector? It is not visible in WSO2 Connector place. In case it is not available from WSO2, is there any third party connector available?

I understand you can expose an Excel file as a Data Service but that is different from a Connector.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WSO2 does not have an Excel connector. I am also not aware of any third party connectors without having too much context about what you are trying to achieve by means of an Excel connector.

Food for thought, try to think of the Excel file as being a kind of database that stores the information. You then in turn setup a datasource connection to the file using the following link as guidance: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Exposing+Excel+Data+as+a+Data+Service
After which you can easily define a query for the data in question.